# django - order by query

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model called `Post` which has two fields `upvotes` and `downvotes`. Now, `upvotes`, `downvotes` are `ManyToManyField` to a `User`. This is the model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    subreddit = models.ForeignKey(Subreddit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    upvotes = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, blank=True, related_name='upvoted_posts')
    downvotes = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, blank=True, related_name='downvoted_posts')
```

I have to make a query where I have to get all posts ***sorted by***

**total (`upvotes`) - total (`downvotes`)**

I have tried `Post.objects.order_by(Count('upvotes'))` to get started but there's an error.

Answer (score 2):

Use [QuerySet.annotate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) first.

```
Post.objects.annotate(
    total_votes=Count('upvotes')-Count('downvotes')
).order_by('total_votes')
```

An added benefit of `annotate()` is that every Post in the queryset gets the `total_votes` attribute, which you can access later with no additional database query or calculation.